# What does l.v. with a dashed line following it mean?

Tags: piano, notation

[image]
In the image above, I see the l.v. symbol with a dashed line following it.

Answer (score 2):

L.v = laissez vibrer. Let ring. As in let the notes played carry on, so they blend into each other. Rather like using the sustain pedal. Or even the sostenuto pedal, if, there is one, and if, your playing is good enough to deploy it properly.

Let ring - written as such, is found in *guitar* music - mainly TAB.